# How to show message in div after ajax success and location.Reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In ajax success call I am doing location.Reload(). After Page reloads I want to show a Message that "Data Uploaded Successfully,". But my page gets reloaded and message get discarded.

```
var data = {
    "strSelectedIds": selectedArray.join(',')
};
var countofProcessedRecords = selectedArray.length;
$("#divLoader").removeClass("display-none");
$.ajax({
    url: UrlSettings.ProcessSubscriptioData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response) {
        location.reload();
        $("#msg").append(
            '<div class="alert alert-success hideit alertSuc">' + countofProcessedRecords + 'subscriptions uploaded successfully.</div >')
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#divLoader").addClass("display-none");
        }, 500);

    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#divLoader").addClass("display-none");
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: get the current location url and add a param to the url, and while loading the page check if the param has value then use that message to show as status.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoud use load() instead of location.reload()
because load() will display the content you want in a div while location.reload will refresh whole your page
Here they're some examples for load() :
In HTML code :

```
<div id="display-content"></div>
```

In Jquery you will need something like this :

```
$("#display-content").load().fadeIn("fast");
```

And as you can also load files inside load() for example :

```
var id = "<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>";
                                                                          
$('#display-content').load('view.php?id='+id).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

To survive the reload you need to use persistent storage like `window.localStorage`.
You would then save a `true` value to the storage, and upon reload then check if the value is `true`.

So, after the successful Ajax call, but before reload you save the value:
`localStorage.ajaxSuccess = 'true';`

Then right after the reload you could check if the value is true, and display the message:

```
if (localStorage.ajaxSuccess === 'true') {
// Display the message here
}
```

However this approach is subject to browser compatibility. And some users can have localStorage disabled or use Safari in incognito mode. 
So another approach would be to load the URL with a parameter instead of `page.reload()`:
www.example.com/uploadPage/?ajaxSuccess

And after reload to check if the URL contains the `ajaxSuccess` string.

Comment: I tried this but localStorage.ajaxSuccess is true on each ajax success.

Answer (score 0):

Use SessionStorage to keep track like this :

```
    var data = {
    "strSelectedIds": selectedArray.join(',')
    };
    var countofProcessedRecords = selectedArray.length;
    $("#divLoader").removeClass("display-none");
    $.ajax({
    url: UrlSettings.ProcessSubscriptioData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "html",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response) {
    sessionStorage.successMessage= true;
        location.reload();

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#divLoader").addClass("display-none");
        }, 500);

    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#divLoader").addClass("display-none");
    }
});

$( function () {
        if ( sessionStorage.successMessage) {
             $("#msg").append(
            '<div class="alert alert-success hideit alertSuc">' + countofProcessedRecords + 'subscriptions uploaded successfully.</div >');
            sessionStorage.successMessage = false;
        }
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That can have some delay before you reload the page. like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: { id: id },
    success: function() { 
        $('#alertMessage').html('<p>success message</p>'); 
        setTimeout(function(){
           location.reload(); 
        }, 800);
    }
});
```